# phonegap-push-plugin register event not called (ios)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

My question is similar to this: [Register event not getting called on ios #386](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/386)

Everything works fine on my android device, but on ios it seems to be that the registration part will be skipped (I get no error or something):

Code:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
            senderID: "XXXXXX"
        },
        ios: {
            senderID: "XXXXXX",
            alert: "true",
            badge: "true",
            sound: "true",
            gcmSandbox: "true"
        },
        windows: {}
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log(data.registrationId);
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log(data.message)
        // data.title,
        // data.count,
        // data.sound,
        // data.image,
        // data.additionalData
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        // e.message
    });
```

Some information what I'm using:

- cordova: 5.0.0
- platforms: android 4.0.0, ios 4.0.0

**EDIT**

I also use this simple notify.js to send my notification to the different devices (works fine for android):

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();

var registrationIds = [];

// Value the payload data to send...
message.addData('message',"Test");
message.addData('title','Hello world' );
message.addData('notId','2');
//message.addData('soundname','beep.wav');
message.collapseKey = 'demo';
//message.delayWhileIdle = true; //Default is false
//message.timeToLive = 1000;// Duration in seconds to hold in GCM and retry before timing out. Default 4 weeks (2,419,200 seconds) if not specified.

// Set up the sender with you API key
//iOS
var sender = new gcm.Sender('API Key iOS');
//Android
//var sender = new gcm.Sender('API Key android');

// Add the registration tokens of the devices you want to send to

//ios:
registrationIds.push('token ios');

//android
//registrationIds.push('token android');

// Send the message
// ... trying only once
sender.sendNoRetry(message,registrationIds, function(err, response) {
  if(err) console.error(err);
  else    console.log(response);
});

// ... or retrying
sender.send(message, registrationIds, function (err, response) {
  if(err) console.error(err);
  else    console.log(response);
});

// ... or retrying a specific number of times (10)
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 10, function (err, response) {
  if(err) console.error(err);
  else    console.log(response);
});
```

**EDIT2**

I finally get this error message:

```
{"multicast_id":xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Comment: Where have you placed this code?...I have placed in method for event deviceready...and sent only iOS with alert,badge and sound.(remove android and windows options).It works for me.

Comment: @sanman thanks for your suggestion, but I always tried this :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by enabling push notification in xcode capabilities.
Make sure you have the latest version.